# Cassandra : 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 218: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, cassandra, cqlsh

I have cqlsh on Ubuntu 16.04 and here's my version of cqlsh :

```
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.10 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
```

I can't create a keyspace and the error I get is this one :

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 218: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I get it to work?

I tried to log in with this command :

```
cqlsh 127.0.0.1 9042 -u cassandra -p cassandra --cqlversion="3.4.4" --encoding utf-8
```

but it didn't work.

Command to create a keyspace that I used :

```
CREATE KEYSPACE Excelsior
       WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 3};
```

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: How you creating keyspace ?

Comment: CREATE KEYSPACE Excelsior
           WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 3};

Answer (score 1):

The error say that `CQLSH` `ascii` encoder can't encode the unicode character u'\xe9' which represent `é`

So when creating keyspace use keyspace name in ascii format.

By the way using your create keyspace command gives me no error, but if i use keyspace name with unicode character like `'éxcelsior'` can produce the exact same error

Comment: the keyspace is from the doc and i tried a bunch of other keyspace names and the same error came up.

Comment: Try to login in cqlsh with `--encoding utf-8` as argument